# Bluetooth socket

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am building tic tac to for two players and need a Bluetooth connection to exchange some data, I can enable Bluetooth, enable discover-ability but my problem in "BluetoothServerSocket" and the client "BluetoothSocket", I don't know how to manipulate this part,
this is the code:

```
ArrayList<String>al=new ArrayList<String>();
        BluetoothAdapter ba = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = ba.getBondedDevices();


        if(pairedDevices.size()>0)  
            for(BluetoothDevice d: pairedDevices)
                al.add(d.getName()+" , "+d.getAddress());

                    if (!ba.isEnabled()) 
                       ba.enable();

                    BluetoothDevice device;
                    Intent dis=new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
                    dis.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION,300);
                    startActivity(dis);

                    BluetoothSocket socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID);
                    socket.connect();

                    InputStream is=socket.getInputStream();
                    OutputStream os=socket.getOutputStream();
```

Answer (score 1):

Both the players will communicate over 'BluetoothSocket's using which you can send/receive data using InputStreams and OutputStreams. But for getting such a pair of sockets you can do this thing :

Create BluetoothServerSocket on the side of one player and other one connects to it. The BluetoothServerSocket listens for connections using the 'accept' method which blocks till a client BluetoothSocket connects to it. After that the BluetoothServerSocket.accept() method returns a BluetoothSocket which can be used with the client Btsocket for 2-way info transfer.

Hope this helps...

PS: createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord just creates one such client mentioned above. You may use the same UUID for both sides

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're missing a lot of complexity regarding data exchange. Mainly you'll need to deal with threads to listen/send data. Here you have a complete implementation of what I'm talking about: https://github.com/buddles/AndBT/blob/master/AndBT/src/br/pucrs/tcii/BluetoothService.java

Have you considered to use an already implemented library? This project comes with a TicTacToe sample and a Chat app that supports up to seven connections: https://github.com/buddles/AndBT

Answer (score 0):

You may refer this [link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/25b6aed7b2e01ce7bdc0dfa1a79eaf009ad178fe/samples/BluetoothChat). This is a simple bluetooth chat app. You can modify this app to send and receive the required data.